# Enable Peripherals in Linux Kernel 3.8.13-rt16

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm running Linux Kernel 3.8.13-rt16 and it is in a headless state (no monitor / keyboard).  I am able to ssh into the box and run commands successfully.  (My 3.8.0-35-generic kernel runs just fine with a monitor and keyboard).

Is it possible for me to enable peripherals on a the rt kernel so I can work directly on this machine?  If so, is this something I would need to change in the source and re-compile, or can this be changed through a configuration file?

I'm new to working with different kernels (especially real time), so any help / suggestions or links to documentation would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By "peripherals", do you mean a monitor / keyboard / mouse? Or something else like a printer or a USB disk or something? Unless that kernel is a severely stripped down one that you've compiled yourself, it's quite likely it has drivers for at least the most common peripheral devices (i.e. it may not know what to do with a force feedback USB pilot's yoke or something).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Try and plug them in. Especially USB devices could work out of the box.

Long answer:

As all hardware (internal or external) needs support by some kernel module, you need first to determine if the peripherals in question are supported by your kernel.

For example, to connect a keybord, you will need PS/2 or USB support. For a monitor, it is neccessary that your graphics chip is supported.

How do you find out which modules to load, and how – if your hardware is supported at all?

First, you need to know what hardware is actually present. This is done via `lspci`. Look for the “VGA controller” and the “USB controller” lines.

A very easy way to see which kernel modules support your hardware, is the [device driver database](http://kmuto.jp/debian/hcl/), which takes your PCI IDs (`lspci -n`) and tells you which modules you can use.

Now, the next step would be to determine if the modules are already in the kernel or if they are available as modules.

It may already be in the kernel. To check this, you can grep through the config¹:

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep MODULE_NAME # uppercase, dashes --> underscores
```

If you see something like `CONFIG_MODULE_NAME=y`, then its in the kernel. If you see `CONFIG_MODULE_NAME=m`, it has been built as a loadable module.

If you don't see the module in the config, or it says that the option is not set, you can still check the actually available modules on your system. To check if a certain module is available, run

```
find /lib/modules/`uname -r` | grep module_name # lowercase, dashes --> underscores
```

If you found your module, you can load it with `modprobe module_name`. `lsmod` should show you if it has been loaded.

If you couldn't find the module, you may have to re-compile the kernel and build the model. I won't cover that here, that's far beyond our scope.

As mentioned before, attaching a keyboard should be very simple.

Expect more difficulties with your graphics chip. Of course, simple VESA output should always work, but for proper support, you may need to tweak a bit. This is also something that I can't cover here; this is a topic for itself (KMS, proprietary vs. OSS drivers, etc.).

Hope that helps for starters. If you need more support, please provide more information about your hardware (lspci -n) and maybe post your kernel config to some pastebin.

*¹ The kernel may have been built without `/proc/config.gz` support. In this case, the config could also be stored in the filesystem, e.g. in the `/boot/` directory.*